# Pathological Question involving $C^1$ Criterion for Differentiability

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Edwards1973 gives a sufficient condition for differentiability:

> If all partial derivatives of $f$ exist at every point of an open set
>   containing $\vec a$, and the partials are continuous at $\vec a$, then
>   $f$ is differentiable at $\vec a$.

I am wondering if the first condition, existence of all partials in an open set containing $\vec a$, is needed. Is the second condition alone, continuity of partials at $\vec a$, sufficient for differentiability?

Another way to phrase this (but in the opposite sense):
Does there exist a function $f$ satisfying these conditions:
1. $f$ is *not* differentiable at $\vec a$,
2. all of its partial derivatives are continuous at $\vec a$, and
3. one or more of the partials are not defined in some parts of any open set containing $\vec a$.

Comment: how about $f\colon \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$ given by $f(x,y)=xy$ if $x,y\in \mathbb Q$ and $f(x,y)=-xy$ otherwise ?

Comment: So far, I managed to show that both partials, $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$, exist only on $x=0$ and $y=0$, and both are identically $0$ on both lines. Both partials are also continuous at $\vec 0$. So far so good! But I'm having trouble showing $f$ is not differentiable at $\vec 0$. (It seems $f$ is continuous at $\vec 0$.)

Comment: Thinking about this more, this $f$ appears to be differentiable at $\vec 0$, so it's not a valid counterexample.

Answer (score 0):

Does Edwards 1973 give additional conditions on $f$ ?  If $f(x,y)= x^2y^2/(x^2+y^2)$ for $(x,y)\not=(0,0)$ and $f(0,0)=0$ the partials exist and are continuous, as functions of $(x,y)$,  at $(0,0)$ , but $f$ is not even continuous at  $(0,0)$.

Comment: I believe I've put in all the relevant conditions on $f$. In your example, are the partials continuous at $\vec 0$?

Comment: Right .The partials are not continuous at 0.Sorry.